# ImagePicker Crash - select image from library and set in an UIImageView when use AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to select an photo from device Gallery and set in UIImage but the device crash after user select the photo from library:

Here is the crash log:

```
Notice: Formulating crash report for process [7997]

Aug  8 10:16:36 iPad ReportCrash[8000] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary

Aug  8 10:16:36 iPad com.apple.launchd[1]
(UIKitApplication:[0x8dd8][7997]) <Warning>:
(UIKitApplication:[0x8dd8]) Job appears to have
crashed: Trace/BPT trap: 5

Aug  8 10:16:36 iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application
'UIKitApplication:[0x8dd8]' exited abnormally with signal 5: Trace/BPT
trap: 5
```

and here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)btnSelecionarFotoClick:(id)sender {
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])  {
        inserindoFoto = YES;
        UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
        [picker release];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo  {
    NSData *dataObj = nil;
    if (image) {
        dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    }

    if (imgUsuario.image) {
        imgUsuario.image = nil;
        [imgUsuario.image release];
    }
    imgUsuario.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imgUsuario.image = image;
    [imgUsuario.layer setCornerRadius:5];
    imgUsuario.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    inserindoFoto = NO;
}
```

**EDIT**

if I cancel without select the picture, crash too:

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I found the problem:

If I disable autoLayout works...but I need to use autoLayout

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: In xcode only "Thread1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe) and the crash log in device

Answer (score 2):

The Apple Documentation states that if you're using the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` for the iPad, you must use a popover controller. You are modally presenting it full screen, which is probably why you are running into issues.

[UIImagePickerController Reference](http://goo.gl/PWQcM)

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your info.plist

For Camera :

Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

For Photo Library:

Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use